# One word for “saying ‘Farewell’ to someone”

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

We have, for example, phrases like, “When I was *greeting* …” in which *greeting* is essentially shorthand for “saying ‘Hello’ to someone” derived from a related verb (to greet).

However, to my knowledge, English does not have a term for “saying ‘Goodbye’ to someone” despite all the related verbs (farewell, goodbye, etc.).

Are there any words which come close to fulfilling such a role? If not, is it due to an absence of such phrases in English's primary language influences (Germanic and Anglo-Francophone), or was it a phrase that existed in those contributing languages but failed to persist in Modern English?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[Leavetaking](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leavetaking)* (or *[leave-taking](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leave-taking#English)*) is “The process of saying goodbye”. Wiktionary gives the following example:

> The formal leave-taking ceremony of a diplomat can take all day [...]

According to [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=leavetaking%2Cleave+-+taking%2Cfarewelling&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cleavetaking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleave%20-%20taking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfarewelling%3B%2Cc0), recent usage of *leave-taking* has been about four times as frequent as that of *leavetaking*, with usage of the latter being five to ten times as high as that of *farewelling*.

Answer (score 18):

Um, the single word for "say farewell" is *farewell*. This is English. You can use any word at all as a verb.

- [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/farewell):

  > **farewell** (third-person singular simple present **farewells**, present participle **farewelling**, simple past and past participle **farewelled**)
  >
  > 1. To bid farewell or say goodbye
  >
  >    - 2009 February 9, Neil Wilson and staff writers, “Tributes for newsman Brian Naylor and wife, killed in fires”, *Herald Sun*:
  >        *He farewelled viewers with a warm sign-off after each bulletin: "May your news be good news, and goodnight."*
- [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/farewell):

  > *transitive verb
  >
  >   chiefly Australian & New Zealand*
  >   :  to bid farewell to
  >   *The retiring teacher was farewelled by the whole school at a special assembly.*
  >   First known use: 1580

Comment: What a lot of things you use 'Farewell' for.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, Gandalf.  And good morning.

Comment: Explains why it's chiefly NZ.

Answer (score 5):

Since the headline formulation of the question asks for the single-word equivalent of a gerund phrase, I will venture a noun: *valediction.* Per OED the verb form *valedict* is “rare.”

Comment: Ideally, the solution would also be a gerund.

Comment: @HalosGhost Does the verb *valedict* not fulfill that criterion? Nevertheless, I am unsure of whether the verb is transitive or in-.  You can *greet* someone, but can you *valedict* him?  Perhaps Brian can answer that quandary.

Comment: @Anonym, perhaps it is due to the rarity of the phrase, but I have never heard _valedicting_ used before. I would also like to see if Brian can elaborate further.

Comment: OED says *intr.;* sole example is itself a definition. And I should think *valediction* itself would serve all the functions of the gerund *valedicting,* though not of the present participle.

Answer (score 3):

Not in particularly common use, but there is a present participle of *farewell*: ["farewelling"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/farewelling).

See, for example, ["Farewelling troops at Lyttelton, 1940"](http://www.nzhistory.net.nz/media/photo/farewelling-troops-at-lyttelton).

Answer (score -1):

**"Goodbyes"** is a single word noun that can be used as you want.  So is **Farewells**

> I said my goodbyes to my school friends at graduation.

Comment: Can you "good-bye" your friends?  That doesn't sound right to me.

Answer (score -1):

**Parting(s/words)** work here.

> done or said by someone when they are leaving

And *adieu* is understood but is similar to saying your goodbyes.

> a farewell remark
>
> I bid adieu to all of my friends before leaving.
>
> Say your adieus before leaving the function.

Answer (score -1):

As [I commented](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174627/one-word-for-saying-farewell-to-someone?noredirect=1#comment364835_174627), "seeing off" is another example in fairly common *modern* usage, and in a similar manner to your use of the word 'greeting'.

It also allows a range of tenses in the normal conjugation of 'to see':

> "I saw them off as they left for their holiday"
>
> "Before seeing them off, I gave their daughter a gift for her upcoming birthday"
>
> "Roger will see you off"

And many others. As you can see these are readily replaced by "greet", "greeting", and "greeted".

Answer (score -1):

The only verb I can think of with any real pedigree is *valedict*, which describes the act of bidding goodbye just as salute describes that of bidding greeting. The Latin etymology of the two words is helpful: *salve*(*te*) is a Latin imperative used to greet someone, from the verb *salveo* (imperative because it really means "be well"); from this verb came the verb *salutare*, to bid greeting, whence the substantive *salutatio*, a greeting. Conversely, to bid farewell, one said *vale*(*te*), another imperative (meaning something like "be strong"); hence the verb *valedico*, to bid farewell, and thence the substantive *valedictio*, a bidding farewell.

From these two Latin verbs come the names of the speeches given at graduation ceremonies in the West -- one to bid greeting (the salutatory speech), and one to bid farewell (the valedictory speech). And thence the common verb "to salute" (and noun "salutation"), as well as the much less common verb "to valedict" (and the somewhat commoner noun "valediction").

I vote we mount a concerted effort to bring "valedict" more into vogue.

Comment: 'Valediction' and the vanishingly rare 'valedict' have already been given, samuel.

Comment: Oh no! I could have been certain I'd read the entire thread. My apologies for the redundancy.

Comment: So deleting the answer to aid others faced with navigating an increasingly lengthy thread seems a good move.

Answer (score -2):

*Dismiss* and *usher out* come close to fulfilling that role.

> [dismiss](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dismiss): to direct or allow to leave
>
> [usher out](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/usher+out): end one's encounter with someone by causing or permitting the person to leave

Alternately, [salute](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=saluted+me+and+left%2Csaluted+her+and+left%2Csaluted+him+and+left%2Cvaledicted+me%2Cvaledicted+her%2Cvaledicted+him&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=8&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csaluted%20me%20and%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csaluted%20her%20and%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csaluted%20him%20and%20left%3B%2Cc0) can also be used as an expression of farewell.

> [salute](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/salute): to greet or address with an expression of welcome, goodwill, or respect
>
> *He [saluted](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=xEwFQ0LH9LAC&pg=PA256&lpg=PA256&dq=%22saluted+me+and+left%22&source=bl&ots=F0xTK7Ktyr&sig=69RtlFhGw5ZJ_Ky6BDN-H6_HEzQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=deaMU8i0FafO0AX5loCQAQ&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22saluted%20me%20and%20left%22&f=false) me and left*.

Comment: _Dismiss_ is close, in that it signals a closing statement, but it focuses on having the recipient of the statement leave. On the other hand, if someone were to use the term I am looking for, it would not necessarily place such emphasis. If any implication were to be made, it would be that the subject is dismissing one's self. If that is helpful and necessary information, I would gladly add it to the OP. Else, your current offerings are a step forward, but not quite solutions.