# What's the verb for the mere act of saying goodbye to someone?

Tags: single-word-requests, greetings

In English there's a specific verb for "say hello", *greet*. What's the specific equivalent verb for "say goodbye"? Some of the alternatives listed [here](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/goodbyes-and-to-say-goodbye) like *see off* and *see out* seem to involve physically following someone to the door. But what if I only want to refer to the act of *saying* alone. For example, when I tell my child to say goodbye to someone and I don't necessarily ask them to show the guest the door but do so myself. There are situations where using the phrase *say hello* is inappropriate and *greet* is a better alternative (in literary prose, or in discussions about non-English-centric cultures for example), so I wonder if there's an alternative to *say goodbye*.

> The Italian word *ciao* is used both to greet and to ___ someone.

Comment: Hmm. I give an answer and then find [something remarkably similar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174627/one-word-for-saying-farewell-to-someone) which also suggests *valedict,* although neither is a word I would actually use.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I checked those answers and it seems there's really no good alternative. I can't really imagine using "to farewell" at all, given how it's labeled as strictly dialectal by Lexico. Case closed then I guess. By the way, how did you put that link over text inside a comment?

Comment: Comments allow a [subset of CommonMark markdown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), and the inline link format is included. That particular way of linking also works in posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lexico does have [***farewell***](https://www.lexico.com/definition/farewell) as a transitive verb, marked as "Australian/New Zealand":

> Mark the departure or retirement of (someone) with a ceremony or party.
>
> > I farewelled my Scandinavian companions, and departed on a Kodiak boat with the Americans Judy, Hank and Cody.